# How redirect to current page after login (Flask)

Tags: python, authentication, flask, redirect

I'm working on a web application for a gym. I created a login system to restrict access to some fields in the application.
My question is the following, I want to know how to redirect the user to the current page after logging in, for example:

> User is on the "Home" page, clicks to login, after logging in return to the home page...

> Just as if he is on the "Nearby gyms" page, after logging in he returns to the same "Nearby gyms" page...

I hope it was clear.

I tried this, but it's giving me an error:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login_form = Login_User()

    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        if login_form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=login_form.email.data).first()
            if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hash, login_form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(request.referrer)
            else:
                flash("Wrong password or Email!")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
                
        return render_template("login.html", login_form=login_form)
    else:
        flash("You are already logged in!")
        return redirect(request.referrer)
```

When I click to login, after registering the page stops working:

[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: When you submit a form via `POST /login` from the login page, the `request.referrer` is going to be `/login`. You're redirecting to the page that you're already on.